# Deep copying linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, implementation

I'm trying to implement a stack on the heap using a linked list.
However, for using the 'list' function I need to create a deep copy of the linked list, which i'm not completely sure how it's done.

Here's a part of my code:

```
class Stack {
    private:
        struct Node  {
           int data;
           Node *next;
       };

        Node *stackTop;

    public:
        Stack() {stackTop = nullptr;}
        Stack(const Stack& original);
        ~Stack();
        bool isEmpty() const;
        int top() const;
        int pop();
        void push(int newItem);
};

Stack::~Stack()   {
        delete stackTop;
}

Stack :: Stack (const Stack& original)   {

// DEEP COPY

}

void list (obj)   {
    cout << "[";
    while(temp -> link != nullptr)
    {
        cout << temp -> data << ",";
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    cout<< temp -> data << "]" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: You may need a public getter function for `stackTop` in `Stack` class since `stackTop` is private.

Comment: Use `std::stack` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Note that the implemented stack is on the heap and the list function is supposed to be outside of the Stack class. If it's possible to display the content without using the copy constructor i'd be glad to know how.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to implement a stack on the heap using a linked list.

To make a deep copy, simply iterate the list allocating new nodes for the `data` values in the source list.

> for using the 'list' function I need to create a deep copy of the linked list*

No, you don't. A function to display the contents of the stack list should not need to make any copy at all.

Try something like this:

```cpp
class Stack {
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node *next = nullptr;
        Node(int value) : data(value) {}
    };

    Node *stackTop = nullptr;

public:
    Stack() = default;
    Stack(const Stack& original);
    Stack(Stack &&original);
    ~Stack();

    Stack& operator=(Stack rhs);

    ...

    void list(std::ostream &out) const;
};

Stack::~Stack()
{
    Node *current = stackTop;
    while (current) {
        Node *next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
}

Stack::Stack(const Stack& original)
    : Stack()
{
    Node **newNode = &stackTop;
    Node *current = original.stackTop;
    while (current) {
        *newNode = new Node(current->data);
        newNode = &((*newNode)->next);
    }
}

Stack::Stack(Stack &&original)
    : Stack()
{
    std::swap(stackTop, original.stackTop);
}

Stack& Stack::operator=(Stack rhs)
{
    std::swap(stackTop, rhs.stackTop);
    return *this;
}

...

void Stack::list(std::ostream &out)
{
    out << "[";
    Node *current = stackTop;
    if (current) {
        out << current->data;
        while (current->next) {
            out << "," << current->data;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    out << "]" << endl;
}

void list(const Stack &obj)
{
    obj.list(std::cout);
}
```